# alert message not closing when validation fails

Tags: javascript, html

Not getting what am I doing wron here. The alert essage never close when the validation fails

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function checkNumber(numField) {
    var num = numField.value;
    if(num < 1) {
        getMessage();
        numField.focus();
    return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function getMessage(numField) {
    alert("Not a valid number. Accepts only postive numbers between ");
}

function setTabOut() {
  document.forms[0].elements['taboutFlag'].value = "true";
}

 
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <input type="text" name="username" onblur="setTabOut();return checkNumber(this);" />

    <INPUT type="hidden" name="taboutFlag" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing this problem because immediately after calling `getMessage` and showing the alert, you focus right back onto the input. When you close the alert, you are losing focus on the input *again*, so the `blur` event is fired, hence the infinite loop.

To solve this, don't focus on the input after calling `getMessage`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function checkNumber(numField) {
      var num = numField.value;
      if (num < 1) {
        getMessage();
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }

    let shownAlert = false;

    function getMessage(numField) {
        alert("Not a valid number. Accepts only postive numbers between ");
    }

    function setTabOut() {
      document.forms[0].elements['taboutFlag'].value = "true";
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <form>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <input type="text" name="username" onblur="setTabOut();return checkNumber(this);" />

    <INPUT type="hidden" name="taboutFlag" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok, then I want the cursor to be in that text box. How do I accomplish that?